# node gm (imagemagick) seems like not working with when invoked with bas64 string as argument

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, imagemagick, gm

I'm not getting any output image when image is not path & is base 64 encoded image.

```
    const image = 'base64 encoded string';

    gm(image, ['jpeg'])
    .resize(72, 72)
    .strip()
    .write('./aks.png', function (err) {
    if (!err) console.log('done');
     });
```

Comment: gm(image) also doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert the Base64 string to a [Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html):

```
var gm = require("gm");
var fs = require("fs");
var image = fs.readFileSync("input.png", "base64");

gm(Buffer.from(image, "base64"))
.resize(72, 72)
.strip()
.write("output.png", function(error) {
  if (error) return console.error(error);
  console.log("Done!");
});
```

Comment: Yes, it is correct that I need to convert the Base64 string to a Buffer.

Comment: But, the typeof(image) is 'base64 encoded string'. So, fs.readFileSync("input.png", "base64"); will not work.

Comment: I'm working on profile picture update api & I'm getting image as base64 encoded string from frontend. I have to compress, resize it & then save it to aws s3.